# html/css bottom border missing

Tags: html, css, border

The bottom border for the .block1 div and .block2 is missing. The .header has all borders, I tried .block and it has borders, but those 2 are missing just the bottom. I can't figure it out. Why is that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.header
{
width: 1500px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid;
margin: 50px;
font-size: 36pt;
text-align: center;
}

.block
{
width: 1500px;
height: 300px;
margin: 80px 80px 80px 50px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.block1
{
width: 950px;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid;
margin-right: 80px;
font-size: 12pt;
text-align: left;
float: left;
}

.block2
{
width: auto;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid;
overflow: hidden;

font-size: 9pt;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
Header (36pt)
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div class="block1">
    Block1 (12pt)
    </div>

    <div class="block2">
    Block2 (9pt)
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
overflow: hidden;
```

To:

```
overflow: visible;
```

change that in `.block`

`.block1`and `.block2` togather with their border are `302px` so you could also change the height of `.block` to `302px` or more

JSFiddle:

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/KYh9R/)

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to CSS Box Model!

This is because borders ADD TO the width/height you have set on elements (as does padding).

since `.block` is 300px tall, and `.block1` and `.block2` are 100%, with the 1px border, they are actually 302px tall.

and since you have `overflow:hidden` on `.block` it is clipping the border.

`box-sizing:border-box` makes box model and sizing behave more logically.

http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/